# How to close the smtp or database ports on our server (cpanel)?

Tags: laravel, port, hosting, cpanel

I am using laravel and Mysql for my project. I have hosted my project on cpanel server. I am using SMTP port to send emails through my project. How should i protect my ports against external attacks as my ports are currently open. How can this be done?